# How to define createdAt and updatedAt in nexus for GraphQL?

Tags: next.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am currently working on GraphQL API in Next.js project w/ TypeScript. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/blog/fullstack-nextjs-graphql-prisma-2-fwpc6ds155) Prisma blog. However, I am not sure how to define the createdAt and updatedAt attributes. They are defined with `DateTime` type in the prisma schema. I am using MongoDB for the database.

```
  createdAt   DateTime      @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt   DateTime      @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
```

Defining the type as string as `string` in the nexus schema is giving type errors.

```js
t.nonNull.string('createdAt');
```

```
Types of property 'createdAt' are incompatible.
    Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Whereas, defining it as `int` throws error `Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: 1661894591365`

```js
t.nonNull.int('createdAt');
```

What should be the data type for createdAt and  updatedAt in order to make it type safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to define a custom GraphQL Scalar when working with `DateTime` values. I would recommend using the [`graphql-scalars`](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars) library and using the `DateTime` scalar. (It's also useful for other custom GraphQL scalars)

The values for the `DateTime` fields are based on the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) when working with Prisma. ([Prisma schema reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#default-value-for-a-datetime)).

Here's also a snippet from `graphql-scalar`'s docs on result coercion.

> JavaScript Date instances and timestamps (represented as 32-bit signed integers) are coerced to RFC 3339 compliant date-time strings. Invalid Date instances raise a field error.

Here's some example usage:

```
import { DateTimeResolver } from 'graphql-scalars'

const DateTime = asNexusMethod(DateTimeResolver, 'date')

t.nonNull.field('createdAt', { type: 'DateTime' })

export const schema = makeSchema({
  types: [
    DateTime,
    /** Queries, mutations, and other scalar types here */
  ],
  /** more config options here */
})
```